# List Item Threshold and Column Limit

Tags: list, threshold

Is there any way by which I can increase or decrease the item threshold for a particular list?

And can anyone tell me the threshold values for below :-

1. Items in a list.
2. Total number of columns in a list.
3. Number of sites in a site-collection.
4. Number of site-collection in a web-application.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Comment: You can only do it on a web application level. And you should read the whitepapers from Akhoy as there can be great impact to an environments performance if you tweak those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boundaries for List:

**File Size:** 2GB per item.

**Document Count:** A flat count of 30,000,000 items per library.

**Item Count:** This is also limited to 30,000,000 items per list.

**List View Threshold:** 5,000 items per view.

**Column Threshold:**

[image]

**

**For Site Collection Threshold**:Recommended number of site collections per farm is 500,000 Personal Sites plus 250,000 for all other site templates

**
**For Site:** The maximum recommended number of sites and subsites is 250,000 sites.

You can  disable throttling at list level but this isn't optimal as you'll see performance issues when sending unoptimized queries to the list.

Please follow this link for avoiding such situations

http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/working-with-list-view-thresholds-in-sharepoint/

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/demystifying-the-sharepoint-lists-thresholds

Comment: Thanks Amit, it was helpful but this is for each and every type of column

I am not concerned with the column type, i want to know at once a list view can have how many fields ?

Comment: so when you are saying fields you are referring to columns?

Comment: yes, i mean columns only,

Comment: I think the answer is that table which I just displayed.In SharePoint there is a concept called row wrapping.To allow for the maximum number of possible columns in a SharePoint list, SharePoint Server will create several rows in the database when data will not fit on a single row.So you can have as many as columns as shown in table unless sum of all columns in a SharePoint list cannot exceed 8,000 bytes and six-row row wrapping limitation. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#Column

Answer (score 0):

in online version no.
in server version yes.

it should not be done as it isn't supported by Microsoft and it will degrade performance of server version.

Comment: how to so that in server version ?